# Interacting with website forms

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to connect to a school url and automate the process with selenium. Originally I tried using splinter, but ran into similar problems. I can't seem to be able to interact with the username and password fields. I realized a little ways in that it is an iframe that I need to interact with. Currently I have:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://my.oregonstate.edu/webapps/login/")
driver.switch_to.frame('Content') #I tried contentFrame and content as well

loginid = driver.find_elements_by_id('user_id')
loginid.send_keys("***")
passwd = driver.find_elements_by_id('password')
passwd.send_keys("***")
sub = driver.find_elements_by_id('login')
sub.click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

Here is the HTML that I am trying to interact with:

The Website: https://my.oregonstate.edu/webapps/portal/frameset.jsp

The iframe:

```
<iframe id="contentFrame" style="height: 593px;" name="content" title="Content" src="/webapps/portal/execute/tabs/tabAction?tab_tab_group_id=_1_1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The forms:

Username:

```
<input name="user_id" id="user_id" size="25" maxlength="50" type="text">
```

Password:

```
<input size="25" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" type="password">
```

It seems that selenium can locate the elements just find, but I am unable to input any information into these fields, I got the error 'List object has no attribute'. When I realized it was the iframe I tried to navigate into that but it says 'Unable to locate frame: Content'. Is there another iframe that I am missing? Or something obvious? This is my first time here so sorry if I messed something up with the code linking.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.switch_to.frame()` takes frame's `id` or `name`, where your frame have id = `contentFrame` and name = `content`. (The reason they didn't work is probably because of a different issue, read through please)

First, please try use either one of them, not `Content` (which has upper case `C`).

Once you have fixed the issue above, there will be another error in your code.

```
loginid = driver.find_elements_by_id('user_id')
loginid.send_keys("***")
```

`driver.find_elements_by_id` finds all matching elements, which is a list. So you can't use `send_keys`. Please use `driver.find_element_by_id('user_id')`.

Here is the code I tested working.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://my.oregonstate.edu/webapps/login/")
driver.switch_to.frame('content') # all lower case to match your actual frame name

loginid = driver.find_element_by_id('user_id')
loginid.send_keys("***")
passwd = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
passwd.send_keys("***")
```

Regarding issue in your following comments

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://my.oregonstate.edu/webapps/login/?action=relogin")

loginid = driver.find_element_by_id('user_id')
loginid.send_keys("***")
passwd = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
passwd.send_keys("***")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.submit.button-1').click()
```

Comment: You were right on the finding elements. My problem however persists with the iframe. No matter what I use, whether it is the id or name, it still is unable to connect. I noticed there is another iframe for the nav bar. But I shouldn't need to connect to that first right? They are separate in the html. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @KJS: I have tested the code above. What environment are you using? I have Python 2.7.5, Selenium 2.42.1, Firefox 24.6.0 ESR. Please try with Chrome, if it works, then it should be a Firefox issue, not the code.

Comment: well i got it working using a different URL to connect. I didn't think it was the code either, but strangely maybe the website. I'm currently using the website: 

https://my.oregonstate.edu/webapps/login/?action=relogin

and it allows me to input into the fields but not select the submit button. I'm using the find_element_by_class_name('submit button-1') but I get the error 'the given selector submit button-1 is either invalid or does not result in a webelement. any thoughts?

Comment: I switched it to find element by name and used 'login' and it throws no errors but doesn't submit the page. So my guess is it can't find the button itself, or there is another element named login. Not sure what to use to make it work though

Comment: @KJS: Clicking login button sounds like a different issue, please raise a new question next time. :) First, you don't need `driver.switch_to.frame('content')` anymore. Then `find_element_by_class_name()` takes ***one*** class name, while you are sending two `submit` and `button-1`. Moreover, you have another element with the same name "login", which receives the click. You need a better locator, e.g. `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.submit.button-1').click()`. Answer updated above. If it fixes your issue, please accept http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235, thanks